# Best way to merge dev branched from older commit on master

Tags: git, github, branch

What is the best way to merge a branch taken from a prior commit off master?

The master branch of a repository I'm working with got about twenty something commits that were unwanted. My colleague is fine with completely losing the unwanted code commits.

When I started working on the code, I branched 'dev' from the last 'good' commit using its hash.

I've committed a lot of new code on this branch and we're seeking to merge that back to the master branch. I believe options include:

1. Hard reset the master branch back to the same commit dev was branched from, and then merge the branches. (I tested this and there was a clean merge, as expected replaying only new code on top of that commit)
2. Replace master branch entirely with dev, since it now includes the full commit history. (Not sure of the best method for doing this)

Perhaps there are other options here, but regardless I am seeking to get both local and remote master and dev branches sync'd up.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the first option of a hard reset on master and merging, you will need to do a force push in order to get the remote master up-to-date correctly.  Depending on the state of other branches this may cause trouble for people when they try to pull updates themselves.  If it just you and your colleague using the repo, this may be fine.

Otherwise, since you don't care about the other commits, you can create a revert commit back to where you branched which will undo the changes and then merge your branch and push without cause as much disruption for everyone else.

The revert command you would use on master would:

```
git revert HEAD..<sha of after branched commit>
```

This should create one commit that will have undone all the others from your colleague and put the repo back into a similar state that you branched from.  The advantage of this is you keep the history and don't need to a force push.

Comment: Thank you. I will upvote and mark correct once I have returned to this merge task and can fully grok and test your solution.